# Converting numerical concrete type to numerical generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to know if there's a specific constraint for numerical types that allows casting to work in the following case:

```
class MyClass<T>
{

...

void MyMethod()
{
    ....
    byte value = AnotherObject.GetValue()

    Tvalue = (T)value;
    ....
}

...

}
```

I tried boxing and unboxing like:

```
Tvalue = (T)(object)value;
```

But this only works if `T == byte`. Otherwise I get an `InvalidCastException`.

T is always a number type (like short, float, and so on).

Comment: What's your purpose? Can you use `Converter`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can only unbox a value to the same type.

Have you tried using

```
Tvalue = (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

? Here's a sample:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestChange<int>();
        TestChange<float>();
        TestChange<decimal>();
    }

    static void TestChange<T>()
    {
        byte b = 10;
        T t = (T) Convert.ChangeType(b, typeof(T));
        Console.WriteLine("10 as a {0}: {1}", typeof(T), t);
    }
}
```

There's no constraint here, although you could specify

```
where T : struct, IComparable<T>
```

as a first pass. That constraint has nothing to do with the conversion working though - it would just be to attempt to stop callers from using an inappropriate type.