# Generic fails when converting int to bool

Tags: c#, generics

I've the following method to search in Registry (don't worry, it's a test using generics):

```
private static T GetValue<T>(RegistryKey key, string name)
{
    using (key)
    {
        return (T)key.GetValue(name);
    }
}
```

But when using type : `Nullable<bool>` it fails because of an invalid cast.
(I tried on numeric keys only)

What I want is to have `null` if key not exists, `false` if 0 is stored in, or `true` else.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks !

Comment: Given that you want *very specific* behaviour based on both the return type (`bool?`) and the key type (numeric), why do you think this should be a generic method?

Comment: Inserting a cast to `dynamic` might help.

Comment: Not very familiar with Registry browsing via C#, but why would you want to Dispose of key after getting the value. Seems like that method doesn't really describe what it does.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's why I said it's a test, i'm not trying to achieve something special, just know how i can "specialize" the type for boolean operations (if I can).

Comment: agreed. Generics do not fit this scenario well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting numerical concrete type to numerical generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661366/converting-numerical-concrete-type-to-numerical-generic-type)

Comment: @ArnaudF.: You're trying to achieve something which is best *not* expressed via generics in .NET...

Comment: And the good answer is for @JonSkeet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because generics cannot utilize type-specific behavior, casts to or from a generic type parameter are assumed to be upcasts/downcasts.

a downcast fails here, you need a conversion.

you can try the `Convert` class, but better to make the type param match the registry type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want such specific behavior (`null` if `null`, `false` if 0, `true` otherwise) then what would your generic method return if T is not a `bool?`?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can stop to use magic cast code. And cast explicitly, so you'll always got what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but magic cast code always fail one day. Explicit never fail, because the compiler can't build.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense, he's already doing an explicit cast.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't use explicit in this meaning. I use it in another meaning, but if I continue no one will understand what I try to explain.

Comment: @Toto, probably best to just delete your answer then.

Comment: @KirkWoll more importantly, how big is your Bengal. I'm kicking around getting one, and would like a bigger cat.

Comment: @Yuriy, ha, you saw my profile. :)  He's a lot bigger than my Siamese, but pretty ordinary-sized compared to most cats.

Comment: @Toto: Since you've been downvoted 3+ times, you'll get the "peer pressure" badge if you delete your answer. Some good can come from being downvoted ;)

Comment: Does I look like I care about badges ? :D

Comment: @KirkWoll ohh well, might try getting another Maine Coon.

Comment: Just trying to put a positive spin on things... ;)

Comment: Very curious to know how we went from type casting to cats :) Swap some letters around and `cast` becomes `cats`...

Comment: Sorry, I have to: I don't see how *explicit cats* will solve the problem either... :)